# Windows Install Compability Advisor Inventory Tool issue

Tags: windows-7, windows

After recent Windows update to my Windows 7 Home Edition, everytime I start a Windows, I see an error:

> Windows Install Compability Advisor Inventory Tool program has stopped working

(Google is trying to correct me, that it should be "*Install **Compatibility** Advisor*", not "*Install **Compability** Advisor*", but I've double checked that name)

Does anyone has any idea, what is going on and how to fix this?

I've searched the net for this issue. But, all I have found so far, is a bunch of forum questions, asking if this software is a piece of Windows or if it can be malicious? Turns out, that this is part of Windows 7, but I found not even a trace about, what is happening to my computer and how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you have malware.  Nuke from orbit. Microsoft does not make spelling mistakes like that unless the Windows installation isn't in English.  I also would remove the last updates you installed to see if the error goes away

Comment: Thanks for an advice. Yeap, that Windows isn't English. It is Polish. Could Polish translation team made such ugly translation mistake (my fellow collegue claims, that this is a Windows service, and disabling it will cease problems).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This file (wicainventory.exe by the way) is no malware, but a part of Windows Update / Windows Installer.
Though it is a missspelling, it is one, that Microsoft has used since Windows XP and in all language versions.

Have a look in C:\Windows\System32\CompatTel\ (at least that's the path used in Windows 7) and in detail view add the column "file description". There you will see, that wica.dll and wicainventory.exe use the word "compability" while other dlls in the same folder are labelled with "compatibility".

To disable it:

- get [Microsoft Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and start it per right-click as Administrator
- go to Options -> Filter Options and uncheck "Hide Windows entries"
- search for aepdu.dll (this is the file that starts the wicainventory.exe)
- in Windows 7 you will find two entries (don't know how many in other Windows versions)
- uncheck both of them
- close Autoruns and restart your pc

Comment: Welcome to Super User and thanks. I gave you voteup (+10 points), but I didn't acceppt your answer (another +25 points), because you only tell, what is this service / file, but you don't say anything how to get rid of that message after each system start. So, you don't directly answer my question. If you, however, edit your answer and add details on removing repeated message during each Windows start, I'll be more than happy to accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the voteup! If my edited answer helped you, I'ld be glad if you would accept it as mentioned.

Comment: So what are the consequences of disabling it? In my case it happily runs on every boot (not crashing) and uses up cpu.

Comment: No consequences for the end user as far as I can tell.
I guess MS uses this tool to collect what hardware and/or software users are using that could bring compatibility issues. But it doesn't seem to have influence in the way that it blocks updates from being installed on a specific system.